# Do we need the [fiction] tag on the Main Site?

Tags: discussion, specific-tag, tags

When looking through the tags on the Main Site I found the tag [fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction). Two of its questions are closed. Two questions use the tags [science](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science) and [fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiction), which looks like the author wanted to use the tag [science-fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) and didn't know that tags are written with a hyphen when you would use a space in normal writing. There is a total of 4 questions with this tag.

I don't see how it is useful for the site, seeing as we already have the often used tag [science-fiction](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/science-fiction) with currently 580 questions. There is no usage guidance or tag wiki that would explain why the author of the first question with this tag, who currently has a bit under 700 reputation, added this tag to the already existing tags. One could argue that "fiction" is a more general term, whereas "science-fiction" specifically states that the question is about fictional elements regarding science, but as WorlBuilding is in itself about creating a fictional world I don't see how using this tag would make questions easier to find. It looks like the tag could be used on basically every question ever asked on the site.

I think we should burninate this tag. What does the rest of the community think?

Comment: Surely, the nature of worldbuilding implies that everything on here is fictional

Comment: Do we need the science fiction-tag?

Comment: @sphennings That might be worth a different Meta discussion. I would probably not use it as a question tagged [tag:science] or [tag:science-based] on a site dedicated to WorldBuilding would be enough, but it's used quite often so I am more reluctant to change it. Burninating [tag:fiction] wouldn't have a big impact on the site, burninating [tag:science-fiction] would definitely have a big impact.

Comment: @Secespitus Mind the difference between [science] (which is a "normal" tag for questions that are *about* science, or about the perception of science, *within* a fictional world) and [science-based] (which is a meta tag for questions that needs answers based in valid science, where the question may be on essentially any subject). Lots of people get that wrong.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Thanks for pointing that out again. A question tagged [science] would already be [science-fiction] on WorldBuilding whereas "science-fiction" normally means "different from real science" and therefore not apply to [science-based] questions that are based on real world science.

Comment: @Secespitus Actually, a question tagged [science] on WB wouldn't necessarily be about anything science-fiction at all, at least not in the common sense, and the tag wiki excerpt seems to support that by saying that the tag is "[f]or questions relating to worlds with a setting of common science-fiction". Science-fiction typically implies settings set in the *future*, but you can just as easily ask a question about (the perception of) [science] in, say, a LOTR-esque world. So [science-fiction] and [science] are not one and the same at all.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling Seems like this topic is more complicated that I thought. I always assumed that "science-fiction" most often relates to future, but is not limited to it. But maybe things from the past fall in different other categories, maybe something like "Steampunk". The tag wiki from [science-fiction] only mentiones "common" sci-fi settings, which I took to be about fictional science, but not limited in the time of the fiction. Maybe we need to adjust the wiki a bit to make it more clear.

Comment: @Secespitus Sounds like a separate meta question to hash out what the respective tag wikis should say might be in order.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling I just looked up the Wikipedia article for [Steampunk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steampunk) and it says in the first sentence that "Steampunk is a subgenre of science fiction or science fantasy". So yeah, another Meta Post is probably a good idea. I will see if I can make one once I find the time.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling [Done](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5238/what-should-be-the-tag-wiki-for-science-fiction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### I removed the tag from the questions

- There hasn't been an answer in 5 days on this question
- There are 4 upvotes on this questions
- The highest ranked comment has 4 upvotes (3 if you don't count mine):

  > Surely, the nature of worldbuilding implies that everything on here is fictional
- Other comments under this question were about a different tag

All in all the community seems to agree as there hasn't been a single indication to keep the tag. The reasons why I think the tag should be deleted have been laid out in the question body.

#### These are the questions that had the tag before I removed it

- [What could be a reason why a more developed civilization isn't helping a less developed one to advance? [closed]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/86513/what-could-be-a-reason-why-a-more-developed-civilization-isnt-helping-a-less-de)
- [How could a Desert planet have an atmosphere?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/84998/how-could-a-desert-planet-have-an-atmosphere)
- [What could threaten a perfectly scientific civilization on Earth? [closed]](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/87895/what-could-threaten-a-perfectly-scientific-civilization-on-earth)
- [Provinces, what are their practical purposes?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/82123/provinces-what-are-their-practical-purposes)